# Could not find Akavache GetObjectAsync method

Tags: c#, system.reactive, akavache

I've installed `akavache` Nuget package (tried v5.0 and v6.0.0-alpha and I am using .NET Standard), but don't have access to `GetObjectAsync` mentioned in many examples through the web. (Even on [the official page](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache)).

I am considering this is rather not Akavache's methods but Rx extensions or something, but could not find if (and where) I can use it.

For instance, `BlobCache.UserAccount` just doesn't have it and I am shown syntax error.

Any clue?

Comment: Almost certain Rx does not have a `GetObjectAsync`. What is that method suppose to do?

Comment: This is a bit odd question to me as long as it's provided on the official page (referenced in my question above).

Comment: Ignore my question. I've provided an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetObjectAsync` was removed from Akavache because `System.Reactive` provides the means to convert an `Observable` in to a `Task`. In fact, an `Observable` can even be awaited.

`GetObject` returns an `IObservable` and can be used in place of `GetObjectAsync`, so long as the `System.Reactive.Linq` namespace is imported.

```
var obj = await BlobCache.UserAccount.GetObjectAsync("toaster"); // old style
var obj = await BlobCache.UserAccount.GetObject("toaster"); // new style
```

Note: An awaited `Observable` is expected to `OnNext` a single value *only*. If `OnNext` is invoked 2 or more times, or not at all, an exception will be thrown. `OnError` will also cause an exception to be thrown.

The documentation [has been updated](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/pull/421#event-1815537604) to exclude `GetObjectAsync` as of 2018.08.28.

Comment: There's a PR to update the README: https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/pull/421